# numberOfRowsInSection called but cellForRowAtIndexPath not called

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, parsing, tableview

In my tableView **numberOfRowsInSection** is called two times but **cellForRowAtIndexPath** not called ? I wants to display Facebook friends list in tableView (if cellForRowAtIndexPath called my problem solved).

I get the right value in my array here but First time when table method called because parsing of friend list not complete it not goes to **cellForRowAtIndexPath** but next time when I reload data it shows value 194(my friends in facebood) in **numberOfRowsInSection** but still not goes **cellForRowAtIndexPath**. I am very tired with that problem ?

```
@implement RootViewController


//In this view i do two things. First use FBFeedPost to Fetch the Friend List from    Facebook and Second navigate to FBFriends view



FBFeedPost *post = [[FBFeedPost alloc]initWithFriendList:self.imageView.image];
    [post publishPostWithDelegate:self];


FBFriends *friendList=[[FBFriends alloc]initWithNibName:@"FBFriends" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:friendList  animated:YES];

@end


@implement FBFeedPost

//After parsing friends list i pass Array to a FBFriend class function   

FBFriends *obj1=[[FBFriends alloc]init];
[obj1 getFreindName:nameItems];

@end



@implement FBFriends


-(void)getFreindName:(NSMutableArray *)friendName
{
    friendsArray=friendName;

    NSLog(@"the count of name is %d",[friendsArray count]);// here i get right answer.

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}


@end
```

Comment: Please summarize the question in the title.

Comment: Insufficient data provided by you.
Also have you set the delegate to self in your method while initializing table view

Comment: what is the problem in reloading when you get the data... everyone does this...

Comment: title of the question looks tags to me :)

Comment: @InderKumarRathore problem is . my [array count] prints 164 in numberOfRowsInSection but cellForRowAtIndexPath not executed

Comment: @janusfidel ha ha ha.. you are right...

Comment: @Stack.Blue: Have you put break point in cellForRowAtIndexPath to check if the the program enters it or not?? Also have you checked if the cellForRowAtIndexPath method has correct spellings??

Comment: if your number of rows is called with 164 then it must call your cellforrow.. for 164 times.. put log in your cellforrow and check it

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper yes.i put break points. it prints [array counts] 164 in numberOfRowsInSection but not execute the cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: @Stack.Blue:What is your table showing after all the methods have executed??does it shows any value or is it empty??? also check for the spellings of your methods..

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper only problem is that my table view not reload again. i attach it with delegate and data source already and my spellings are right.

Comment: @Stack.Blue: Put a break point on [self.tableView reloadData];
and check if the table view has memory or it is nil.

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper you are right .. memory nil. now what to do? when first time view did load call it works fine but for second time memory nil;

Comment: @Stack.Blue:Are you navigating into too many classes simultaneously??? or you may have added the tableview through XIB. Try to create it programatically in the viewDidLoad.That may solve it.

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper .. first thanks. yes i am navigating into two classes. i create table view programmatically . but my viewDidLoad methods calls only once. see my code above you understand clear.. FBFriends class object two time created 1) for navigation to that view and 2) for passing array by method. hope you understand my problem

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper. thanks a lot you give me your time . now i am changing my all code.. thanks again :)

Comment: You are welcome:) do let me know if there is again some issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Stack.Blue:ok what property have you used for tableView??Use `@property(nonatomic,retain)UITableView *tableView;` 
or next option is you can try adding the table in `viewWillAppear` method.Do let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks. For me, it was the `retain` keyword that did it. In my case, using ARC, it was the `strong` keyword.